# how to send mass emails/messages to a persons friends on facebook

Tags: facebook, invite

I am making a site , where some guy who has a facebook account can invite his friends.

The problem is that the standards facebook API provides a popup for such case , where a user who wants to invite his friends has to manually click each friend he wants to invite , after that click enter.

How can I mass send messages/notifications on facebooks to those said friends of my customer ?
Same question about sneding emails , although I doubt one can ever get the frineds emails form facebook.

Please give me advice. At least tell me how to automate the "select all the friends from the popup" process.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You have to use the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). It's a security measure which ensures that apps cannot send invitations to a user's friends without approval from the user.

Comment: faceBook did this with EVERY SINGLE ONE social network before them. And now they will not allow others to do what they did. Cruel greedy corrupted people....